# Laravel 4 & Basset collections

Tags: laravel, assets

My installation seems fine, as the default 'application' collection works.

However I tried to create a new collection, but I can't seem to get a proper build:

In my global.php (in the docs, it says it has to be somewhere in config/packages etc. but I guess that only applies for Laravel 3?) I put the following:

```
    Basset::collection('preview', function($collection)
    {
        $collection->stylesheet('stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css');
        $collection->stylesheet('stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.min.css');
        $collection->javascript('javascripts/bootstrap.min.js');
    });
```

So I thought, just create a build "preview" with artisan:

```
php artisan basset:build preview
```

Output:

```
[preview] Stylesheets build was not required for collection.
[preview] Javascripts build was not required for collection.
```

And when I look in my folder "builds", I only see the application collections, no new folder "preview" with the added sheets/scripts.
Also loading it in my view using @stylesheets('preview') does not do anything.

Any suggestions to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: You need to publish Basset config first - `php artisan config:publish jasonlewis/basset`, and put your collection information to file in `app/config/packages/jasonlewis/basset/config.php`. I'm not sure if putting Basset collection in global.php will work.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to add a file in config/packages that is picked up by the Basset plugin - the easiest way of doing this is running `artisan config:publish jasonlewis/basset`.

Then, add your collection to the `collections` array, e.g.:

```
'preview' => function($collection) {
    $collection->stylesheet('stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css');
    $collection->stylesheet('stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.min.css');
    $collection->javascript('javascripts/bootstrap.min.js');
},
```

The [docs](http://jasonlewis.me/code/basset/4.0/collections) do imply that you can do it this way, but I haven't figured out where - this config method does work however.

Answer (score 0):

After you've published the config using `php artisan config:publish jasonlewis/basset` navigate to app\config\packages\jasonlewis\basset and edit the config.php there.

Then, add your collection to the collections array, e.g.:

```
    'collections' => array(

    'application' => function($collection)
    {
        // Switch to the stylesheets directory and require the "less" and "sass" directories.
        // These directories both have a filter applied to them so that the built
        // collection will contain valid CSS.
        $directory = $collection->directory('assets/stylesheets', function($collection)
        {
            $collection->requireDirectory('less')->apply('Less');
            $collection->requireDirectory('sass')->apply('Sass');
            $collection->requireDirectory();
        });

        $directory->apply('CssMin');
        $directory->apply('UriRewriteFilter');

        // Switch to the javascripts directory and require the "coffeescript" directory. As
        // with the above directories we'll apply the CoffeeScript filter to the directory
        // so the built collection contains valid JS.
        $directory = $collection->directory('assets/javascripts', function($collection)
        {
            $collection->requireDirectory('coffeescripts')->apply('CoffeeScript');
            $collection->requireDirectory();
        });

        $directory->apply('JsMin');
    },

    'login' => function($collection)
    {

        $directory = $collection->directory('assets/stylesheets', function($collection)
        {
            $collection->stylesheet('bootstrap.min.css');
            $collection->stylesheet('metro.css');
            $collection->stylesheet('font-awesome.css');
            $collection->stylesheet('style.css');
            $collection->stylesheet('style_responsive.css');
            $collection->stylesheet('style_default.css');
            $collection->stylesheet('uniform.default.css');
        });

        $directory->apply('CssMin');
        $directory->apply('UriRewriteFilter');

        $directory = $collection->directory('assets/javascripts', function($collection)
        {
            $collection->javascript('jquery-1.8.3.min.js');
            $collection->javascript('bootstrap.min.js');
            $collection->javascript('jquery.uniform.min.js');
            $collection->javascript('jquery.blockui.js');
            $collection->javascript('jquery.validate.min.js');
            $collection->javascript('app.js');
        });

        $directory->apply('JsMin');            

    }

),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this/

```
'collections' => array(

'application' => function($collection)
{
    // Switch to the stylesheets directory and require the "less" and "sass" directories.
    // These directories both have a filter applied to them so that the built
    // collection will contain valid CSS.
    $directory = $collection->directory('assets/stylesheets', function($collection)
    {
        $collection->requireTree();

    });

    $directory->apply('CssMin');
    $directory->apply('UriRewriteFilter');

    // Switch to the javascripts directory and require the "coffeescript" directory. As
    // with the above directories we'll apply the CoffeeScript filter to the directory
    // so the built collection contains valid JS.
    $directory = $collection->directory('assets/javascripts', function($collection)
    {
        $collection->requireDirectory();
        $collection->javascript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js');
    });
}
```